# Real Time Malaware scanning using Maldetect : Rejected by the approver script

Tags: apache, cpanel, mod-security2, clam

I have a cPanel server with apache 2.4 and Maldetect, ClamAV. I want to have realtime malware scanner on server to block hackers from uploading malicious files on server. What i meant is when someone uploads a file, apache will invoke the scanner using mod-security 2.9 and scan the uploaded file.

**If it's found as malware - should get rejected. 
If it's found good file - should upload to correct destination.**

I have tried to do this with following settings as described in https://www.rfxn.com/appdocs/README.maldetect

```
To enable upload scanning with mod_security2 you must set enable the public_scan option
in conf.maldet (public_scan=1) then add the following rules to your mod_security2 
configuration. These rules are best placed in your modsec2.user.conf file on cpanel servers
or at the top of the appropraite rules file for your setup.

/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf (or similar mod_security2 rules file):
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecRule FILES_TMPNAMES "@inspectFile /usr/local/maldetect/hookscan.sh" \
                "id:'999999',log,auditlog,deny,severity:2,phase:2,t:none"

If using ModSecurity >=2.9, you should set 'SecTmpSaveUploadedFiles On' before the
'SecRule FILES_TMPNAMES' line.

A restart of the Apache service is required following these changes.
```

But the **problem is all the files are getting rejected by doing this, even good files**. Is there anything wrong with the above setup?

```
# cat /usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf
### UPLOAD PARAMETERS BEGIN ####
SecUploadDir /tmp
SecTmpDir /tmp/
SecDataDir /tmp/
SecUploadKeepFiles RelevantOnly
### UPLOAD PARAMETERS END  ####

SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecTmpSaveUploadedFiles On
SecRule FILES_TMPNAMES "@inspectFile /usr/local/maldetect/hookscan.sh" \
                "id:'999999',log,auditlog,deny,severity:2,phase:2,t:none"
```

Following is the error in logs

```
[Sun Mar 05 21:11:35.936553 2017] [:error] [pid 9800] [client x.x.x.x] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). File "/tmp/20170305-211135-WLxNz@kP@rKcABIc7ZF3lAAAAAM-file-SfujtQ" rejected by the approver script "/usr/local/maldetect/hookscan.sh": Linux Malware Detect v1.5 [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "13"] [id "999999"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "x.x.x.x"] [uri "/test.php"] [unique_id "WLxNz@kP@rKcABIc7ZF3lAAAAAM"]
[Sun Mar 05 21:11:44.511418 2017] [:error] [pid 9526] [client x.x.x.x] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). File "/tmp/20170305-211144-WLxN2EJsvK1FL3paCDmxrgAAAAE-file-iQx2zR" rejected by the approver script "/usr/local/maldetect/hookscan.sh": Linux Malware Detect v1.5 [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "13"] [id "999999"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "x.x.x.x"] [uri "/test.php"] [unique_id "WLxN2EJsvK1FL3paCDmxrgAAAAE"]
```

Comment: "#/usr/local/maldetect/hookscan.sh <filename>  "  this will work fine , but when using via apache it rejects all files :(

Comment: How do you upload those files? within the browser via a php script or anything similar?

Comment: uploading via a php script, you can see it from the error. [uri "/test.php"]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Problem is this line:

> SecTmpSaveUploadedFiles On

Try to remove it from the rule.